# Remove array of features (OpenLayers 4)

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Am trying to remove an array of features from OpenLayers 4 map. 
I don't want to clear all features in the source. Added few selected features to an array.

Currently, am iterating array and using this. `source.removeFeature(array[index]);`

Instead of looping many times is there is any way to remove features in an array at one time?

> Note: I don't want to remove all features in the source, but just the
>   features which I have added to my array

**Code:**

```
var docketSource = new ol.source.Vector({
    url: dataUrl,
    format: new ol.format.TopoJSON()
});
var redFeatures = [];
function removeRedFeature(redFeatures) {
   for (var i = 0; i < redFeatures.length; i++) {
       docketSource.removeFeature( redFeatures[i] );
   }
}
```

Comment: @nCore No, did not find it

Comment: i´m doing exactly the same thing and i don´t think that´s a "wrong" way

Comment: @nalm Am not saying its wrong way, but instead of looping, we may do it in one line right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `source` is an `ol.source.Vector` you can execute `clear()` by doing:

`source.clear()`

I'm a little confused with what you're asking, but you've mentioned "selected features". Perhaps this is what you're after?

```
var select = new ol.interaction.Select();
select.getFeatures().forEach(function(feature){
   docketSource.removeFeature(feature);
});
```

See http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#clear for more information.

**UPDATE**: There is a `removeFeatures` function in **OL 2.13.1**.

> removeFeatures: function(features, options)
>
> *Remove features from the layer.  This erases any drawn features and removes them from the layer’s control.  The beforefeatureremoved and featureremoved events will be triggered for each feature.  The featuresremoved event will be triggered after all features have been removed.  To suppress event triggering, use the silent option.*

See: http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Vector-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.removeFeatures

Comment: source.clear() works for all features in that source right. That's not what I want. Am trying to remove few selected features from the source at one time.

Comment: @TejaMaridu What's the problem with using `removeFeature()` to do that? You mention it's not the right way to do it but it actually is the right way to do it.

Comment: I don't have an issue with removeFeature(), But I want to remove features at a time instead of iterating and removing each one.

Comment: @TejaMaridu "..at a time instead of iterating and removing each one." - please elaborate on that. It's not really making any sense at the moment.

Comment: @Fuzz I'm also have trying to find a solution, `removeFeature()` is only removes single feature in the source, so if you have multiple features (e.g. 1000) that needs to be removed it will take some time. In OL2/3 there was a function `removeFeatures([features])` which removed an array of features.

Comment: @fuzz yeah unfortunately doesn't exist in OL4 anymore which is a shame, because there's a way to add bulk features but not remove.

Comment: @nCore Correct, like I mentioned in my answer. OL4 recommends to use `source.clear();` if you want to remove all features.

Comment: @Fuzz, Nevermind I might have found my solution, probably not the best but works ok as an alternative.

Comment: @nCore Can you share what you ended up doing?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is one solution but you can also use `docketSource.getFeaturesCollection()` that returns a `ol.Collection` of `ol.Feature`s. Then, you can manipulate the returned collection and use the function `remove`

So, you could do `docketSource.getFeaturesCollection().remove(yourfeature);`
However, if you need to loop through the collection, you will use `forEach` method of the collection and it would be similar to your solution.

Look at [`ol.Collection` methods](http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.Collection.html) to see if they could fit better with your purpose.

Answer (score -3):

removeFeature is the only API function to remove some features from an ol.source.Vector . (See https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/v4.6.5/src/ol/source/vector.js )

If you have problems with lots of events fired or something like that, you could extend the ol.source.Vector class and implement a removeFeatures function, for example modifying the clear function or merging clear with removeFeature.