# How to remove array of features in Openlayers 4, not using clear()

Tags: javascript, openlayers

`removeFeature()` function works great but not so much when trying to remove a lot of features/markers from the source as it only removes single feature. There was a function in OL2 that does this but removed in OL4.

Is there a work around to achieve this?

```
features.forEach(function(feature, ind, array){
      if(feature.id == selectedFeature)
      {
        // slow removing process as it removes a single feature from the source...
        tFeature.removeFeature(feature);
      }
    });
```

Was hoping to do something like this instead of removing a feature as it iterates through the source.

```
var removeF = [];
features.forEach(function(feature, ind, array){
 if(feature.id == selectedFeature)
 {
   // push every features that needs to be removed..
    removeF.push(feature);
 }
});
// Remove it in one go..
tFeature.removeFeatures(removeF );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569967/5355375

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove array of features (OpenLayers 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559988/remove-array-of-features-openlayers-4)